# Constraints on a derived attribute - Postrgres

Tags: postgresql, constraints, derived

I have a derived attribute - age in a table in PostgreSQL which is calculated using the current date and the date of birth of each person. How can I set a constraint to only accept a person that is 18 years of age or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CHECK (age(date_of_birth) >= '18 years');
```